# $K$-theory for non-compact manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory, k-theory

It seems that usually (by which I mean, in every source I've looked at) people define the group $K^0(X)$ for $X$ compact Hausdorff.  Sometimes they later extend this definition to all locally compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ by defining $K^0(X)$ to be $K^0(X^+)$ of the one-point compactification $X^+$

The question is:  why not just take the original definition of $K^0(X)$ for all locally compact Hausdorff $X$?  Isomorphism classes of vector bundles on any such $X$ forms a commutative monoid, and so we should be able to take the Grothendieck group just the same, no?

Comment: You won't get a cohomology theory this way, see the recent discussion at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182420/the-space-of-fredholm-operators-as-a-classifying-space

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks!  I am completely satisfied with this answer.

Comment: @DmitriP. Do you have an easy example where the product axiom fails for such defined K-theory?

Comment: @Kamil: If you mean the wedge axiom, it already fails for the wedge of spheres S^n (n≥0) since to represent K-theory classes of spheres you need vector bundles of arbitrarily high dimensions, whereas a vector bundle on a wedge of spheres has a fixed finite dimension.

Comment: @DmitriP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we don't use the same definition of $K^0$ for non-compact spaces as we do for compact spaces, is because the resulting set of functors would not form a cohomology theory.

Source:  A comment of [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182420/the-space-of-fredholm-operators-as-a-classifying-space).  Thanks to Dmitri Pavlov for pointing to this reference.